# prevent inadvertant tab close in chrome, etc

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In Chrome I typically have 10-15 tabs open and am constantly doing two things:

Accidentally closing tabs when clicking on them because I hit the X instead.

Accidentally dragging tabs off the browser onto their own new window.

Which extension prevents this.  If possible I would disable the X, and the drag to new window  feature as well.  How easy is it to write an extension to do this.

Comment: Not yet: http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/UBPg5GuRDKM

Comment: Actually,  I accidentally close the tab much more often than dragging it off the browser - but both are highly annoying and inconvenient.  Just a context menu option for both is all that's needed.

Comment: As a side note, there's a "Reopen closed tab" option in the file menu (command-shift-T on Mac) that might be a more straightforward solution to accidentally closing tabs.

Comment: As for myself, I'm constantly closing questions which are crazy offtopic, and I can't seem to help myself.

Answer (score 0):

I will write my first chrome extension and provide an update here when finished.  Should be a simple matter to use chrome.tabs to automatically pin every new tab that's created.

---

Code is trivial so:

bg.html:

```
    <script src="bg.js"></script>
```

bg.js:

```
var id = 0;

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {

  id = tab.id;

  var t = setTimeout("update_tab()",100);  

});


function update_tab()  {

  updateProperties = new Object();
  updateProperties.pinned = true;

  chrome.tabs.update(id, updateProperties);

}
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "FanTabStick",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Pin down all tabs automatically",
  "background_page": "bg.html",
  "icons": { "128": "icon.png" },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]}
```